# MicroSD Card and SPI

Tags: c, embedded, spi, atmega

I am trying to read/write on MicroSD card by program SPI. By oscilloscope I see that CS and MOSI and CLK are working correct.
By "correct" I mean that CS is up, but when I send CMD it is low, then up again; MOSI send CMD correctly, a bit before first CLK and at this time in MISO I try to catch something; CLK: it makes clocks about 4 uS between fronts.
I am sending 10 x 0xFF above CMD0, and I am doing this after any CMD.
I send:

```
SPI_send(CMD0, (unsigned long) 0x00, 0x95);
SPI_send(CMD8, (unsigned long) 0x01AA, 0x87);
SPI_send(CMD58, (unsigned long) 0x00, 0x01);
```

But all what I see is 1 on MISO.

It happends only if MicroSD card IS in cardreader. If it is not, MISO is always 1.

MicroSD Cards I try are 2 and 4 Gb. May be it is meanfull. They works if I connect them to my PC.

If it'll help, I will write my code here to write byte

```
for(int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)

    {

        if (byte & 0x80)
            PORTG |=SPI_MOSI;
        else
            PORTG &= ~SPI_MOSI;
        PORTG |= SPI_CLK;
        byte |= (PINE & SPI_MISO)>>6;
        byte <<= 1;
        PORTG &= ~SPI_CLK;
    }
```

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: "a bit before first CLK" This doesn't sound right. You can configure SPI that to get clocked out at rising or falling clock edge (clock polarity), and you can configure it to be sent out with half a bits delay from the clock edge (clock phase adjustment). But you can't configure it to send data before the first clock edge.

Comment: MicroSD cards may not support SPI mode.

Comment: Note: use fixed width types if you need a specific bitwidth.

Comment: @Lundin Im sorry, a bit I meaned 1uS before clock, I saw it here: http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/gfx1/cmd.png . Have I misunderstand it?
And I am making my SPI, non hardware.

Comment: @Lundin: Some SPI peripherals setup the first bit before the clock edge (possibly gated wit `SS`) in some POL/PHA combinations. Not sure if that is true for ATmega, though

Comment: @Olaf Well, I'm not surprised... since there is no SPI standard and there is not even a SPI de facto standard. I'm surprised there is no commercial interest of fixing it once and for all. Every device manufacturer who uses SPI seems to have a competition over who can implement it in the dumbest possible way.

Comment: @Lundin: Hmm, most times the low-level works quite ok once you figured out the correct combinations. It isthe higher levels which suck for most devices (MCU and peripherals). The standard problem : hardware-engineers without knowlede of software-design and clean communication protocols. To be fair: i2C has it's pitfalls, too - despite an existing and quite long "standard".

Comment: Ok, I tryed to send only CMD0 with 0x00 and CRC of 0x95 and there is nothing in MISO, always 1. Will now remake post

Comment: a quick look and the atmega328p seems to limit itself to four modes (which is not all the combinations).  then you have to look at your target documentation and understand the edges, not modes, edges.  two separate busses, one sends on one edge the other samples on some edge.

Comment: Not from a datasheet or spec, but some random web page:  Data is clocked into the host or card on the rising edge of CLK and changes on the falling edge.

Comment: the spi mode for this media is documented as well as being able to get documents for the specific or some of the specific vendors, refer to those, start with mosi certainly, and then see if the card responds.  as Olaf pointed out not all cards support spi

Comment: sd card spi is a PITA BTW.  I would learn spi with something simpler.  like a nokia 5110 display or making an avr isp programmer, or a spi flash or something like that.